# Android - Application should not be closed on screen locking

Tags: android

I am facing an issue in my application. When i am running my application and click on device lock hardware key and again unlock the device, the application is closed. I want the application to get launched on the same activity i was before locking the device.

I tried google but i could get code samples only on locking the device through code. But, i want my application to stay active even if the device is locked.

Please help me if you have pointers for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the issue ... i was finishing the activity in my onPause Method. Once i removed it, application was working as expected.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onResume function and give the override . Here is a sample code,

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
        }
```

If you need to give any other functionalities mention it inside the onResume().

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using a Custom ROM that closes applications on key-lock, this never happened with me.